# Java: How is a blank character represented?

Tags: java, string

I had run a mySql query from ant, and had the output in "out.txt". In this file, right after listing the rows in the table, there is:
           <-- this line is an empty line
0 rows affected

In Java, i am trying take out.txt and make it more readable. I want to ignore the empty line. I have tried:
 if (!(myStr.contains("\n") ) 
but it does not work. I have tried "" and null too.

This line is bothering me because when i add some html tags, it is getting in at the very end, and messing up the way the html table looks.

Comment: how are you reading your file? `bufferedReader`? `scanner`?

Comment: BufferedReader. The empty line was in the original input file. I'm wondering how to catch it in Java.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your workflow is `database->ant->out.txt->Java-> what`? You want to make an empty line more readable? myStr is a String, from the mySql-Query or from reading the file back in? I would first try

```
 (myStr != null)
```

just to be sure, then

```
 (myStr.isEmpty ())
 // or 
 (myStr.length () == 0)
```

If you tried "" - was it `(myStr == "")` or `(myStr.equals (""))`?

Comment: FWIW - `myStr.isEmpty()` is more elegant than `myStr.length() == 0`, though the former is only available for Java 6 and later.

Comment: myStr == null doesn't mean an empty line. It means either an uninitialized member variable or else a failure to read a line, e.g. readLine() at EOF.

Comment: Yes, depending on the surrounding code, you might not need `== null`.